# Entity Framework DBContext.Entry() is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to get some data out of the database. Using the .Entry is very slow, over 65% of time spent is right there. Does anyone have any ideas how to optimize my query? I only want to get the data as read only.

[image]

Sorry about adding the code as an image, but it would not let me post the question when it was formatted using the code sample button.

Comment: Is this done in a loop? I think it would be easier to help if you shared some more code. Because it's not reasonable that this should be noticably slow if it's not in a loop. Unless you have an insane amount of entities loaded into that context.

Comment: What's the lifespan of the context?

Comment: I have updated the question with more code. There can be thousands of surveys. When profiling 67% of the time is spent inside LoadSurveyGraph() and 65% of that is spent on winPicsDbContext.Entry(seismic2DSurvey)

Comment: This must be related to the number of entries in the context. Consider a different approach, e.g. loading entities with `AsNotracking()` and using `Include`s. By the way, it's easy to paste and format code. Just make sure everything has at least 4 spaces indent.

Comment: Gert Arnold, you were correct it had to do with the number of entities in the context. I was able to read an article on it and they talk about context bloat. It ended up being much faster to recreate the context multiple times then trying to do everything in one.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is definitively far from being optimized. Try this instead:

```
seismic2DSurvey.EndsAndBends = winPicsDbContext.Locations
    .Where(t => t.surveyId = seismic2DSurvey.Id && (t.IsBend || (t.IsEnd.HasValue && t.IsEnd.Value))).OrderBy(t => t.TraceNumber).ToList();

seismic2DSurvey.TraceCount = locations.Count();
seismic2DSurvey.SurveyLocations = null;
```

Comment: winPicsDbContext does not contain locations. It contains .SurveyLocations but that is not loaded (included) that is why I was calling entry and .Collections to query its .SurveyLocations. .Include was much more slow.

Comment: Have you considered using Lazy Loading instead of Eager?